# Different total results in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Im currently analyzing different data about user of an application. Unfortunately I can't share our data but I was able to rebuild the problem with the public bigquery data.

First I summed up the Users (which are 199.681):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT visitId) as Users,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.*`
WHERE date BETWEEN '20170501' AND '20170820'
```

Then I want to see the distribution into operating systems:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT visitId) as Users,
  device.operatingSystem
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.*`
WHERE date BETWEEN '20170501' AND '20170820'
GROUP BY device.operatingSystem
ORDER BY Users DESC
```

And I get these results ( which are 202.008 in total)

```
Users   operatingSystem
67846   Windows
47923   Macintosh
34645   Android
33130   iOS
9683    Linux
7395    Chrome OS
1066    (not set)
172     Windows Phone
87      Samsung
38      BlackBerry
10      Xbox
7       Nintendo WiiU
5       Firefox OS
1       FreeBSD
```

If I perform these variations for different categories (e.g. country), I always get different total results. Is there anyway to fix this problem or is the code wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! How about if you swap your current user definition to `COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) as Users`, do you see your numbers match now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching your query around a bit...

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  count(distinct device.operatingSystem) as os_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.*`
WHERE date BETWEEN '20170501' AND '20170820'
GROUP BY 1
HAVING os_count > 1
```

and you can see that there are some visitIds that have multiple operating systems. In your first query each visitId is counted once, and in the second query each visitId will be counted once per each operatingSystem.

In this particular scenario it could be an error in the source data or it is an intentional choice in how GA is 'sessioninizing' a visit.  For your use case, decide what best represents your business and go with that.